# How Can I Fix Reflected XSS Clients in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, xss, clients

How can I fix a reflected XSS client problem on ASP.Net? Can anyone help me?

The problem is below:

**Reflected XSS Client**

**Method :**

ROW:563

```
Private Shared Function bindSiteMenu(TSql As String) As Data.DataTable
....
563.                  DRow.Item("Sortby") =  dt1.Rows(i).Item("Sortby").ToString
564.                  dtAll.Rows.Add(DRow)
....
569.          Return dtAll
```

**Method :**

```
Public Shared Function FrontSiteMenuForSMap(ByVal SiteID As Long) As 
Data.DataTable

                ....
529.          Return bindSiteMenu(TSql)
```

**Method :**

```
Protected Sub SiteMap(SitID As Long)

    ....
    27.          Dim dt As Data.DataTable =
    SiteMenuObj.FrontSiteMenuForSMap(SitID)
    ....
    29.              SetNodes(dt, SitID, 0, 0, "")
```

**Method :**

**ROW:77**

```
Protected Sub SetNodes(ByVal dtTree As Data.DataTable, ByVal SiteID As Long,ByVal ParentId As Long, ByVal Level As Integer, ByVal TreeNumber As String)

....
33.      Protected Sub SetNodes(ByVal dtTree As Data.DataTable, ByVal
SiteID As Long, ByVal ParentId As Long, ByVal Level As Integer, ByVal
TreeNumber As String)
....
36.          rows = dtTree.Select(filterExpr)
37.          If rows.GetUpperBound(0) >= 0 Then
....
47.              For Each row In rows 
48.                  tmpParentId = row.Item("ParentId").ToString
49.                  tmpFDefaultLink = row.Item("FDefaultLink").ToString
50.                  tmpMenuTitle = row.Item("MenuTitle").ToString
51.                  tmpMenuID = row.Item("MenuID").ToString
52.                  tmpSiteID = row.Item("SiteID").ToString
53.                  tmpURL = row.Item("URL").ToString
....
71.                          Url = tmpURL
....
77.                      litF.Text = "<li " & css & "><a href=""" & Url
& """ title=""" & tmpMenuTitle & Title & """>" & tmpNumber & tmpCount &
"." & tmpMenuTitle & "</a><ol>"
```

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: so you have just some variable cancatenated into string :  litF.Text = "<li " & css & "><a href=""" & Url
& """ title=""" & tmpMenuTitle & Title & """>" & tmpNumber & tmpCount &
"." & tmpMenuTitle & "</a><ol>"  , what's the error ??? I think you don't have declared some variable like: css, Url, etc verify that

Comment: @CristiC777 also i dont know error is where, but when i scan with checkmark im getting this result. litf is a literal object I declared all variables

Comment: Use Breakpoints to check your variable values. ex at line 53.

Comment: @CristiC777  tmpURL = row.Item("URL").ToString is blank

Comment: so in your current row the column (celll) with header/name "URL" is empty..  check why ! :)

Comment: because, this page is siteMap module, then some url is blank some url is not, so if i have a blank url should be fill with "#" ? right ?

Comment: yes, or use If isNothing ..

Comment: @CristiC777 thanks for your attention. i will be try

Comment: Wellcome ! :)  and use google ;)

Comment: google !? whats is it ? new technology ? XD.. im searching it but dont find any article about this ;) sometimes ask real people better than google :)